# Is this type of question on-topic for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

Can I ask [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80951/dont-know-how-to-transform-complex-attribute-into-relational-table) on Stack Overflow as well?

If this question is on-topic, can you suggest me tags, because this would be my first time asking this type of question?

Comment: Even if it was on-topic, you should not cross post.

Comment: @Oded: OK, thank you. I have decided to leave it there and not post it on SO. Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not on-topic on Stack Overflow. It's a database administrator (DBA) question, and it belongs on the DBA site.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying it. I will leave that post on DBA site and will not post on SO. Best regards.